# How to configure delimiters in vue.js version 3+ using build tools?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, delimiter, mustache, compiler-options

I was stuck with this for a while.

The official site gave this:

> ```js
> // Delimiters changed to ES6 template string style
> app.config.compilerOptions.delimiters = ['${', '}']
> ```

but it doesn't work for build setup only as mentioned in the site.. it only works for standalone vue.js

Comment: If you want to post an answer to your own question, use the answer box below. Don't post the answer in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks @tony19  .. I have been a lurker for so many years. just figuring out how to get involved.. i have been helped by this site so much, i wish to give back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @Emperorsum's own answer here:

> Anyway this finally worked:
>
> Editing vite.config.js thus:
>
> ```js
> // https://vitejs.dev/config/
> export default defineConfig({
>   plugins: [vue({
>     template:{
>       compilerOptions: {
>         delimiters: ["[[","]]"]
>       }
>     }
>   })],
>   resolve: {
>     alias: {
>       '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))    
>     }
>   },
> })
> ```